# Какое нужно писать окончание? Нужно ли согласовывать окончания?

Tags: окончания

Вот такое предложение:

"Окружающая среда, в которой существует политическая система, формируется из двух составных частей: интрасоциетальной, которая включает в себя экономику, культуру, социальную структуру, межличностные отношения и экстрасоциетальной, **включающ...**(ая/ей) все системы, являющиеся внешними по отношению к обществу, которые выступают функциональными компонентами международного общества."
Какое окончание нужно вставить на месте пропуска?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поставить вопрос к "экстрасоциетальной части":
- Частью какой?
- Включающ**ей**.

Вообще, если вас не тревожит повторение слова "которая", то можно заменить на "...и экстрасоциетальной, которая включает все системы...".

Answer (score 0):

На вопрос об окончании Вам дан ответ, но предложение нуждается в редактировании, например:

Окружающая среда, в которой существует политическая система **общества**, формируется из двух составных частей: **интрасоциетальной,** которая включает в себя экономику, культуру, социальную структуру, межличностные отношения,  и **экстрасоциетальной**, **куда относятся все внешние по отношению к данному обществу  системы, являющиеся функциональными компонентами международного общества.**

Предложенный вариант сложен для прочтения и понимания, также там много однотипных конструкций, что является стилистической погрешностью